# PowerMockito doesn't mock the new instance called in the tested class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

I have the following class where, in the constructor, I call another constructor to build a field of the class:

```
public class ClassIWantToTest {
    private ClassIWantToMock anotherClass;
    public ClassIWantToTest() {
        //some stuff
        anotherClass = new ClassIWantToMock(); //<-- call constructor to build the field
        //some other stuff
    }
}
```

When I test the class `ClassIWantToTest`, I want to mock the instance of `ClassIWantToMock`.

Hence, I've set up my test as follows:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassIWantToMock.class)
public class ClassIWantToTest_Test {
    @Test
    public void myFirstTest() {
        ClassIWantToMock myMock = PowerMockito.mock(ClassIWantToMock.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassIWantToMock.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myMock); 
        ClassIWantToTest test = new ClassIWantToTest(); //<-- not mocked
    }
}
```

However, in the last line of code in the test (where I make a `new` of the class I want to test), the constructor of `ClassIWantToMock` is still called.

I've searched other examples on Stack Overflow (and in documentation), but it seems that it should be done like this. What am I forgetting/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a simple mistake. If the class `ClassIWantToMock` is initialized inside `ClassIWantToTest`, then also `ClassIWantToTest` should be prepared for test.

I replaced this:

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassIWantToMock.class)
```

with this:

```
@PrepareForTest({ClassIWantToTest.class,ClassIWantToMock.class})
```

... and it worked fine.